# Can this graph search be optimized?

Tags: java

I have the following which searches my graph to see if a vertex is reachable from the first vertex, which everything should be connected to. I do this to ensure there are no disconnected parts.

Unfortunately it is very slow.

Is there something I could do or store to optimize this?

I want to learn about graphs and generated cities so Im not using a real graph library.

```
private void removeDisconnectedSquares()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < getNumXNodes(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < getNumYNodes(); ++j)
        {
            //removeDisconnectedSquare(i, j);
            visitedNodes.clear();
            if(!isNodeReachableFrom(getNodeAt(i, j), getNodeAt(0, 0)))
            {
                removeVertex(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isNodeReachableFrom(GraphNode node, GraphNode target)
{
    if(node == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(visitedNodes.contains(node))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        visitedNodes.add(node);
    }

    if(node == target)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(node.contains(target))
    {
        return true;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < node.getSize(); ++i)
    {
        if(isNodeReachableFrom(node.at(i), target))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using recursion (which is pretty slow), you can for this using a Set of all reachable nodes, and a Queue of nodes you still haven't searched.  This is a basic implementation of Breadth-First Search.

```
private boolean isNodeReachableFrom(GraphNode start, GraphNode target) {

    // These are GraphNodes who's connected GraphNodes we haven't looked at yet.
    // Maybe the target is connected to one of these!
    Queue nodesToSearch = new LinkedList<GraphNode>();
    nodesToSearch.add(start);

    // These are GraphsNodes which we have proved are reachable from the given node.
    // If we are ever about to add the given target to this list, we return true.
    Set reachableNodes = new HashSet<GraphNode>();

    // As long as there are still nodesToSearch, we could still find our target.
    while (nodesToSearch.peek() != null) {
        GraphNode node = nodesToSearch.remove();

        // If we have already seen this node, we don't want to look at its connected
        // nodes again, because we could get stuck in a cycle.
        boolean isNewNode = reachableNodes.add(node);

        // If this is a new node, see if the target is connected.  If it is, we are
        // done successfully.  Otherwise, add all of the connected nodes to our
        // list of nodesToSearch.
        if (isNewNode) {
            for (GraphNode connectedNode : getConnectedNodes(node)) {
                if (connetedNode.equals(target)) {
                    return true;
                }
                nodesToSearch.add(connectedNode);
            }
        }
    }

    // There are no nodes we haven't searched, so the target is not reachable.
    return false;
}
```

Note: I made up `getConnectedNodes(node)` because your code didn't show me how to do this with the GraphNode object.

Note that this is an implementation of `isNodeReachableFrom`.  However, you seem to want to figure out the list of nodes which *aren't* reachable from a starting node.  Notice that we build up the list of all `reachableNodes` in the call above, which is probably what you really want.  You could write a function to return that reachableNodes structure, which would reuse the above logic without the `target` sections.  Something like this:

```
public Set<GraphNode> getReachableNodes(GraphNode start) { ... }
```